# Disable fingerprint fail sound

Tags: huawei, fingerprint

When I accidentally touch fingerprint sensor when phone is locked, it emits a beep sound, meaning that scanning failed.

Can I disable this annoying sound?

I have a Huawei P10 with Android 7 OS.